# How to create a ConstantInt in LLVM?

Tags: llvm

I'm not sure how to create a ConstantInt in LLVM- I know the number I would like to create, but I'm unsure how I can make a ConstantInt representing that number; I can't seem to find the constructor I need in the documentation.

I'm thinking it has to be along the lines of

```
ConstantInt consVal = new ConstantInt(something here).
```

I know I want it to be an int type, and I know my value... I just want to create a number!

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196009/set-value-for-llvmconstantint

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most things in LLVM are created through a static method call instead of directly using a constructor. One reason is that an existing object can be returned instead of creating a new instance.

The [static members of ConstantInt](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantInt.html#pub-static-methods) have a number of creation methods. You're probably most interested in `get (Type *Ty, uint64_t V, bool isSigned=false)` and, if you don't already have an integer type, `IntegerType::get (LLVMContext &C, unsigned NumBits)`.

Comment: So how would I go about creating it? I'm currently trying
    ConstantInt::get(Int64Ty, iVal)

And that's not working... what's getting me is how I tell it it's an Int64Type without it complaining at me. I've tried Type::Int64Ty and other variations to no success.

Comment: @winepretzel If you're having problems with compilation errors or something like that you should add the code you're trying and the error messages you get to the question.

Answer (score 6):

To make an a 32 bit integer:

```
llvm::ConstantInt::get(context, llvm::APInt(/*nbits*/32, value, /*bool*/is_signed));
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a `32-bit` integer constant:

```
llvm::Type *i32_type = llvm::IntegerType::getInt32Ty(llvm_context);
llvm::Constant *i32_val = llvm::ConstantInt::get(i32_type, -1/*value*/, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ConstantInt* const_int32  = ConstantInt::get( Context , APInt(32, StringRef("10"), 10));
```

where,
    APInt(32, StringRef("10"), 10);
gets int value from string "10" with base 10.