# Function pointer as Argument to call

Tags: llvm

I am trying to create a call to a function `foo` that receives a function pointer (with signature `void bar(void)`) as argument. From [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803848/llvm-insert-pthread-function-calls-into-ir) post I got the basic Idea to accomplish this.
First I register the Foo function. Bar is actually a function that has been compiled by LLVM so there is no registration neccessary.

```
FunctionType* BarType =  FunctionType::get(Type::getVoidTy(getGlobalContext()), false);

Type* FooType[1];
FooType[0] = static_cast<Type*>(BarType)->getPointerTo();
ArrayRef<Type*> FooTypeARef(FooType, 1);

FunctionType* signature = FunctionType::get(Type::getInt32Ty(getGlobalContext()), FooTypeARef, false);
Function* func = Function::Create(signature, Function::ExternalLinkage, "Foo", TheModule);
LLVM_ExecutionEngine()->addGlobalMapping(func, const_cast<void*>(&Foo));
```

This is how the actual call is inserted (**Case I**)

```
std::vector<Value*> ArgsV_Foo;
Function *FooFun= LLVM_Module()->getFunction("Foo");
Function* BarFun = LLVM_Module()->getFunction("Bar");

ArgsV_Foo.push_back( BarFun );

LLVM_Builder()->CreateCall(FooFun, ArgsV, "calltmp")
```

However, this aborts inside CreateCall with the reason "Calling a function with a bad signature". I am not sure if the line `ArgsV_Foo.push_back( BarFun )` is correct.

A different approach that seems possible to me is to use ExecutionEngine to get a pointer to Bar, but I do not understand how to convert the resulting function pointer to a `llvm::Value*` (**Case II**)

```
std::vector<Value*> ArgsV_Foo;
Function *FooFun= LLVM_Module()->getFunction("Foo");
Function* BarFun = LLVM_Module()->getFunction("Bar");

void* BarFunPtr = LLVM_ExecutionEngine()->getPointerToFunction(BarFun);
Value* val = ??
ArgsV_FEFork.push_back(val);

LLVM_Builder()->CreateCall(FooFun, ArgsV, "calltmp")
```

Maybe someone has an idea how to accomplish the second case or confirm that the assignment in the first case is correct (and the problem sits elsewhere).

Comment: So thanks to Oak I found the problem. Compiled functions are not void types of course...So i fixed BarType to i32 Bar ( void )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Regarding the 1st case:

I'm not quite sure what's going on there. Why do you upcast `BarType`, for example? In any case, an easy way to check it out would be to call `->dump()` on all the types involved and check out for yourself what the differences are.

Also, avoid using `static_cast` on LLVM objects - [there are more canonical ways to cast](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-isa-cast-and-dyn-cast-templates).

#### To solve the 2nd case:

1. Cast the function pointer (`BarFunPtr`) to an integer.
2. [Create a constant integer in LLVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246920/how-to-create-a-constantint-in-llvm) using the result of (1) as the value. Remember - anything that you compute outside the JITted code is a constant as far as that code is concerned.
3. Cast the constant integer from (2) to a pointer via `inttoptr`. The pointer's type should be a function pointer matching `bar`'s type.
4. Use the result of (3) as the call target.

#### Regarding `ArrayRef`s

Finally, just FYI, there are easier ways to create `ArrayRef` instances.... In particular you might be interested in [its **implicit** single-element constructor](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ArrayRef.html#a3b1f44186f9787d7ffacb54b62d6798c) :-)